# Custom "didn't allow" page

Tags: authentication, facebook-authentication

As you can see, some Facebook games have custom page for "Didn't allow" user action. It shows when applicataion try to install and user click "Didn't allow"

f.e. - Cityville by Zynga - http://gyazo.com/6e398bfa6b803a23cfc36a32a6956e48.

How can I make the same page for my app?

Answer (score 0):

If the user did not "allow" your application, he/she will be redirected (via HTTP 302) to the URL specified in the `redirect_uri` parameter that you specified in the authentication parameters with the following data :
`http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&
     error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.`

All you have to do is handle this data and display the message that you want to the user.

This information (and a whole lot more) can be found in the [facebook authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)